# Pass reference to a pointer

Tags: c++

I have the following problem in C++:

```
class Class3
{
    //...
};

class Class1
{
public:
void func1(Class3* class3Pointer)
{
    Class3 *myClass3 = new Class3();

    //The newly created object myClass3 should be referenced by class3Pointer
    class3Pointer = myClass3;

    //But I need to work with myClass3 object now in main function below, after myClass3 has been initiated.

    //I want to do that while a loop is sleeping
    while(true) {
        sleep();
    } 
}

};

class Class2
{
    public:
    void func2(Class3* class3Pointer)
    {
        Class1 *Class1Object = new Class1();
    Class1Object->func1(class3Pointer);
}

};




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Class3* class3Pointer;

    Class2 *myClass2 = new Class2();

    myClass2->func2(class3Pointer); //Calling in a new thread

    //Here, I need to work with object myClass3 instantiated in Class1->func1

    return 0;
}
```

In the main method I want to refer with myPointer to the Object created within Func2.
How can I do that? I think, the way above is wrong because it is just passing the myPointer twice by value. How can I pass the pointers by reference?

Thanks for any help. The use case is tcp socket programming.

Best,SpeedyV

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Comment: The first link explains value references, which you need to know for your 1st problem. Alternatively you could use a pointer of pointer.

Comment: I have a bad feeling about how your threading is going to go ; you need to protect any variables that will be accessed by multiple threads

Comment: The second tells you about threads, which let you have several parts of the same program executing simultaneously (concurrency).

Answer (score 1):

Make the function take its argument by reference:

```
void func1(Class3* & class3Pointer)
// ----------------^
```

Then changes to `class3Pointer` in the function will also change the argument that was passed (in fact both of those two things will denote the same variable).

Comment: I am wondering, what will happen to myClass3 as it is declared locally? Wouldn't that invalidate the pointer?

Comment: @Hayden `myClass3` points to dynamically-allocated storage, and `class3Pointer = myClass3;` means to make `class3Pointer` point to where `myClass3` is pointing.

Comment: Ahh okay, missed the dynamic-allocated part (well didn't think of that).